# BOSS RC-300 Memory.rc3 file format

Tags: looper-pedals

What is the Memory.rc3 file format for the BOSS RC-300 Loopstation?
I want to set up a key-value text file to make batch edits.

Comment: Do you have one at hand?  Did you try opening it with a good text editor (I'm not taking about word)?